# Evaluate a unix command within for loop

Tags: bash

I wish to print from `i.res` to `POSCARi+1`.

1. `i.res` are files with names `1.res`, `2.res`, `3.res`, etc. These files are sitting in the working directory.
2. `POSCAR(i+1)` are files with names `POSCAR2`, `POSCAR3`, `POSCAR4` respectively. I need these files in the working directory.

I am using this loop:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do convert $i.res POSCAR[$i+1]; done
```

The results are:

```
POSCAR1+1
POSCAR2+1
POSCAR3+1
```

I want the expression to be evaluated, and give `POSCAR2` for `1.res`, `POSCAR3` for `2.res` and so on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. What is `POSCAR`? It looks like it's supposed to be an array. Is it? What happens when you run this code? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: You still haven't explained what "POSCAR" is. Is it an array or not? Is it a string? Do you just want the word `POSCAR` and `$i+1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print `POSCAR` and the current value of `$i` plus one, you can try:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do convert $i.res POSCAR$((i+1)); done
```

The `[$i+1]` syntax won't be understood by the shell. For arithmetic evaluation, you need `$(( ))` instead.